# how to find the position of the maximum value for a probability distribution function plot?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Given a Probability Distribution Function (at least in the form of two arrays of y and P(y)), I know how to find the maximum probability through its index using the following line:

```
 i_max=np.argmax(P)
 max=P[i_max]
```

However, I also need to know the location of this maximum along the y-axis. I could not find any statement in scipy to do that. Theoretically, this is easy to do. But, I don't know how to implement it in python3. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, lost you. Why isn't this `np.max(P)`?

Comment: Actually that will work too. But, initially I thought that having the index corresponding to the maximum value is more interesting and maybe more helpful in using it to locate the position of the maximum.

Comment: Is `y[i_max]` what you want?

Comment: I actually tried that too. All it does, it gives you the maximum value of y-axis which is not needed in this case. Location of maximum value is somewhere in the ragne [y[0], y[i_max]]. Thanks again,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem before and I didn't know the argmax method.
What I did was
index = np.where( np.max(P) == P )
It may help you

Comment: Thanks dear Stefano, when I put P (which is an array of discrete values of p(y)), it is not working. But, when I replace P with the functional form of the pdf (defined earlier in the code), it actually gives you a 1D array of two elements whose lower/upper values are just corresponding to the indexes just before and just after the location of maximum. Maximum is located at y=10 theoretically and I get [  9.98998999  10.01001001] which is nice given the discrete nature of the pdf.

Comment: Honestly I hardly can understand your problem, I provide you another issue I had that may help you

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
y = np.sin(np.pi*x)
plt.plot(x, y)
a = plt.ginput(1)

then clicking on the graph you get something like

a = [(-0.375, -0.7792887029288702)]

that are the x and y components of the point you chose with your mouse. To find which is the closest x component to -0.375 type

np.where( x > a[0][0])[0][0]

where
np.where( x > a[0][0])[0]is an array of all the indexes which have values bigger then -0.375 and

np.where( x > a[0][0])[0][0]

is the first element of this array